# Securing Data Files on Windows C++

Tags: windows, security, c++11, file-io

Hello I am looking to see if there is a good way to secure files on windows. Currently I am writing and reading files to windows using C++ like so:

Write:

```
string filePath = GetStorageFilename(SomeFileName);

ofstream dataFile;
dataFile.open(filePath, ios::out | ios::binary);
dataFile.write((char*)data.data(), data.size());
dataFile.close();
```

Read:

```
using std::basic_ifstream;
using std::istreambuf_iterator;

auto fileName = GetStorageFilename(dataDescriptor);
basic_ifstream<uint8_t> file(fileName, ios::binary);
return ByteVector((istreambuf_iterator<uint8_t>(file)), istreambuf_iterator<uint8_t>());
```

I was wondering if there might be a better method since this is sensitive data. Essentially the data will already be encrypted in a secure environment. But I would like a way to prevent non-administrative users from writing the data and reading it even though the data will already be encrypted. It would be nice for it to require administrative privileges in order to prevent denial of service scenarios.

Thank you,

Answer (score 0):

The easiest solution is to use a directory that's already restricted to administrative users. Do you mean the built-in Administrator account, or do you have an administrative role in your own program? In the first case, you can use NTFS security as-is. If not, you'll need to create your own "FooAdmin" group, create a directory restricted to "FooAdmin" members